# Ordering data frame in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, plyr

I have the following data frame structure:

```
    Animal          Food
1    cat      fish, milk, shrimp
2    dog      steak, poo
3    fish     seaweed, shrimp, krill, insects
```

I would like to reorganize it so that the rows are in descending order of number of factors in the "Food" column:

```
    Animal          Food
1    fish     seaweed, shrimp, krill, insects
2    cat      fish, milk, shrimp
3    dog      steak, poo
```

Is there an R function that can help me with that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `count.fields` to figure out how many items there are in each "food" row and order by that.

```
count.fields(textConnection(mydf$Food), ",")
# [1] 3 2 4
```

Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf":

```
mydf[order(count.fields(textConnection(mydf$Food), ","), decreasing=TRUE),]
#   Animal                            Food
# 3   fish seaweed, shrimp, krill, insects
# 1    cat              fish, milk, shrimp
# 2    dog                      steak, poo
```

Answer (score 1):

make a new variable and sort by that, edit: thanks to Ananda and alexis

<del>`df$nFood<-length(unlist(strsplit(df$Food, ",", fixed=T)))`</del>

```
df$nFood<-sapply(strsplit(df$Food, ","), length)
```

Comment: A late +1, because this seems fast. Also, faster than `sapply(...)` should be `unlist(lapply(...))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can order the frame according to the results of your counting function:

```
animals = data.frame( rbind(c("cat","fish, milk, shrimp"),
                  c("dog","steak, poo"),
                  c("fish","seaweed, shrimp, krill, insects")))
colnames(animals) = c("Animal","Food")
animals[order(sapply(animals$Food, function(x) { length(strsplit(as.character(x),split=",")[[1]]) })), ]
```

I put in the `as.character` because it defaults to a factor, you probably don't need it (quicker) alternatively you can use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating the data frame.